# How should I proceed further to solve this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'd like to solve the following differential equation by reducing it to normal form:

$y'' +2xy'+(x^2+5)y=xe^{-x^2/2}$ $(*)$

This is what I have done so far:

Let $y=uv$ be the complete solution.

Then, $v=e^{\int -(P/2)dx}$, where $P=2x$

So I get, $v=e^{-x^2/2}$

Now, to find $u$, $(*)$ can be reduced to normal form:

$u'' +(4-x^2)u=x$  $(**)$.

My question is how do I solve $(**)$ to get $u$?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Start from the beginning with $$y=z \,e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$$ and you will arrive to something very simple.

Comment: Should I substitute $y=e^{-x^2/2}(u)$ in the original equation? And thank you for answering!

Comment: @NatashaJ. Yes and tell me your resulting DE.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This is what I arrived at $u''+4u=x$. I did not know we could solve like this as well! You taught me something new. Thank you!

Comment: @NatashaJ. You are very welcome ! Glad to help